# Is 'painstaking' positive or negative?

Tags: meaning

The word 'painstaking' has a such [entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/painstaking) in merriam-webster.

Does this word have a positive meaning or a negative one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the Merriam-Webster entry for [**painstaking**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/painstaking):

> : taking pains : expending, showing, or involving diligent care and effort
>   // *painstaking* research
>   // *painstaking* tasks
>   // *painstaking* accuracy

Neither *diligent care and effort* nor *painstaking* have any positive or negative meaning. *Painstaking* itself is neutral, but you can use it in the *context* of something that is either positive or negative.

---

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=painstaking) says the following about *painstaking*:

> 1550s, *paynes taking*, "assiduous and careful labor"  (n.), 1690s, "characterized by close or conscientious application, laborious and careful" (adj.), from plural of pain (n.) in the "exertion, effort" sense + present participle of take (v.). Related: *Painstakingly*.

As such, it is *not* related to the sense of [pain](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pain) that means discomfort or distress, but to its other, plural, sense:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **3** **pains** *plural* : trouble, care, or effort taken to accomplish something
>   // was at *pains* to reassure us

Comment: Thank @Jason Bassford! It's a complete description. You should have your own Dictionary. :) . and; According to Jackson_ITGuy12, answer below, Can I assume that 'painstaking' is neutral by nature, but is usually used in a negative sense? Thanks you so much...

Comment: @elyarabad I would not say that it's *usually* used in a negative sense. *The finest of artisans take pleasure in their **painstaking** approach to their craft*. There is no clear interpretation if the sentence as a whole is something negative or positive, generally positive with a negative component, or simply a statement of fact (neutral). When ***I*** hear **painstaking**, I think **careful**, which, to me, is, if anything other than neutral, actually positive. But that's just my personal association with the word.

Comment: That' an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way that I typically use the word "painstaking" is in a negative connotation (that is, meaning).

For instance, "I put hours of painstaking work into that job, all to get fired?"

**Edit:**

Thanks, @Fivesideddice.

I use the word in a negative *context*, however the word itself is describing the work I put in, so the adjective is being used in a positive *manner*.

Comment: Maybe you mainly use the word in a negative *context*, but is the word itself used in a  negative manner there?

Comment: I guess not. It’s describing the work being put in, work you’re defending. I’m amending my answer.

Comment: Dear @Jackson_ITGuy12! Since your bio says you're a native speaker of English; Can I assume that 'painstaking' is neutral by nature, but is usually used in a negative sense? -thanks!!!!!

Comment: @elyarabad That sounds right. It’s neutral in nature, but typically used in a negative sense.